# Assistant RECORD_HEALTH_OBSERVATION missing value

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I'm trying to integrate with `actions.intent.RECORD_HEALTH_OBSERVATION` to track weight in an app. Everything seems to work via the App Actions Test Tool (v3.2.0), but when I attempt to test by speaking to the Google Assistant, the actual weight value (e.g. 180) is not present--all other parameters show up as expected.

My `actions.xml`:

```
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.RECORD_HEALTH_OBSERVATION">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="myapp://track-weight?referrer=assistant{&amp;weightValue,weightUnits}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="healthObservation.value.value"
            urlParameter="weightValue" />
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="healthObservation.value.unitText"
            urlParameter="weightUnits" />
        </fulfillment>
    </action>
</actions>
```

The test tool shows:

```
{
"@context": "http://schema.googleapis.com",
"@type": "HealthObservation",
"value": {
    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
    "unitText": "Kilogram",
    "value": "83"
}
```

Again, when testing via the App Actions Test tool/adb, both `weightValue` and `weightUnits` appear with the expected values--but when saying "Ok Google, record that I weigh 180 kilograms with My App", then *only* `weightUnits` appears in the query string.

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue. Please report this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:617864%20status:open).

Comment: Created this issue for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155108399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Please let me know if it doesn't work for you. Also, if it works, mark this question as solved.